# Problems to integrate a form into a block

Tags: forms, blocks

So far, the form is rendered in the block, but the following errors are displayed:

> Notice: Undefined index: ios_lang_checkbox_nameform_function in
>   drupal_retrieve_form()
>
> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, function 'ios_lang_checkbox_nameform_function' not found or
>   invalid function name in drupal_retrieve_form()

```
<?php

function ios_lang_checkbox_block_info() {
  return array(
    'ios_lang_checkbox' => array(
      'info' => t('Ios Like language switcher'),
      'description' => t('Ios Like language switcher')
    )
  );
}
function ios_lang_checkbox_block_view($delta='')
{
    $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('ios_lang_checkbox_nameform');

  switch($delta) {
    case 'ios_lang_checkbox':
      $block['subject'] = null; // Most forms don't have a subject 
      $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('ios_lang_checkbox_nameform_function');
      break;
   }
   return $block;
 }

function ios_lang_checkbox_menu() {
    $items['ios_lang_checkbox'] = array(
        'title' => 'View the sample form',
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('ios_lang_checkbox_nameform'),
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM
    );
    return $items;
}


/**
 * Define a form.
 */
function ios_lang_checkbox_nameform($form, &$form_state) {

    $options = array(
        'de' => t('de'),
        );
    $form['ios'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Your Name'),
        '#type' => 'checkboxes',
        '#description' => t('Choose language'),
        '#options' => $options,
    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Submit')
    );
    return $form;
}


?>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You've left `_function` on the end of `ios_lang_checkbox_nameform_function`...just change that line to `$block['content'] = drupal_get_form('ios_lang_checkbox_nameform');`. The string passed to `drupal_get_form` needs to be exactly the same as the function name itself, no need to put `_function` on the end :)

Comment: What @Clive said, as I was about to ask are you sure it's showing up in the block and not the page, eg on page `yourhost.com/ios_lang_checkbox` as defined in your menu?

Comment: @Jimajamma thanks for asking. As far as i understand it i implemented both...do I ? I really don't see how I should gasp all that *cryformommy*

Comment: @Clive why dont you put it togeher into an answer? Than i can at least give you some points for you extraordinary nice help

Comment: I don't understand your cryformommy, but I was asking because from looking at your code, the page would work, since it is calling `drupal_get_form('ios_lang_checkbox_nameform');` while your block was calling a nonexistent one, eg, one with `_function` at the end of it.

Comment: @Jimajamma ah got it! hmm in fact that is weired... by the way do you know some good intoduction into the most important api. i think i might not gasp the context of all that...so complicated...thats way i cry for mommy...but i think she can't help me...

Comment: @Jurudocs Get yourself a copy of [Pro Drupal Development](http://www.drupalbook.com/), it's got pretty much everything you need to know in it

Comment: @Jimajamma but you are totally right. The form now shows up in the top left but i didn't activate any block...?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got `_function` on the end of `ios_lang_checkbox_nameform_function`...just change that line to:

```
$block['content'] = drupal_get_form('ios_lang_checkbox_nameform');.
```

The string passed to `drupal_get_form()` needs to be exactly the same as the function name itself, no need to put `_function` on the end :)