# How to display a contact form as a node block?

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a content type let’s say "hotels" and there are a bunch of nodes for different hotels. I would like to display a content form either as a block or in the node itself, where users can send an e-mail to the accordant hotel owner.

How can I do this? I have tried using display suite and entity reference but could not get this to work.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

For non coding solution, you can go with

Create the form using **[Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform)** and utilizing **[Webform Blocks](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_block)** and **[Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token)**

> Webform is the module for making forms and surveys in Drupal. After a submission customizable e-mails can be sent to administrators and/or submitters. Results can be exported into Excel or other spreadsheet applications. Webform also provides some basic statistical review and has an extensive API for expanding its features.

---

**[Form Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/formblock)**

> Enables the presentation of user registration, site wide contact, or
>   node creation forms in blocks. This is particularly useful for
>   including forms on panels.

Worth mentioning, just might not do for this question's specific use case.

---

Do it programmatically by creating a custom block and fetching the form, you can find an example here [Problems to integrate a form into a block](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/42498/problems-to-integrate-a-form-into-a-block/42501)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have tried to set this up but struggle in displaying a block with an accordat web formular as a block. How does this work in detail?